# Diamond of stars in c

Tags: c

I am trying to draw this diamond so that after the middle row, the rest of the diamond is shifted 3 spaces to the right, as though you were looking at it through a glass of water.  Could you somehow modify the code below to incorporate this shift?

The output should look something like:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
      *****
       ***
        *
```

(but with up to 15 stars in the middle).
Thanks!

```c
define TOTAL_ROWS 15
int main() {
    int row, col, numstars=1;
    int half, rate=1;

    for (row=1; row<=TOTAL_ROWS; row++) {

        half=TOTAL_ROWS/2

        for (col=0; col<half+1-numstars; col++)
            printf(" ");

        for (col=1; col<=2*numstars-1; col++)
            printf("*");

        if (numstars==(half+1))
            rate = -rate;

        numstars+=rate;  
        printf("\n");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the code do right now? Are you seeing errors?

Comment: Hooray, the year loops around to star patterns :-)

Comment: Can you somehow modify this code so that the diamond it produces shifts 3 spaces to the right?  See the example output above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just check if row is bigger than half and add those 3 spaces...

```
if(row>half+1)
    printf("    ");
```

See [fiddle](http://cfiddle.net/sDddvu).

Answer (score 1):

When you *switch* to the other half set a flag and print 3 spaces thereafter.

```
int flag = 0;

    ....


  if (numstars==(half+1)) {
        rate = -rate;
        flag = 1;
    }

    numstars+=rate;

    printf("\n");
    if (flag) printf("   ");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

On the first inner for, you can start the `col` variable with `-3` if it is past the center:

```
for (col=(row <= half+1 ? 0 : -3); col<half+1-numstars; col++)
    printf(" ");
```

I think it is enough and easy.